# How to make DOM to image nicer

Tags: javascript

I need to render an application form to png image and open in a new tab/window, here is how I do it now:

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.style.background = 'white'
node.style.width = '190mm';
node.style.margin = '0mm';
node.style.marginColor = 'white';
node.innerHTML = sourceHtml;
document.body.appendChild(node);
setTimeout(function() {
  domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function(dataUrl) {
      document.body.removeChild(node);
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      var win = window.open('' + dataUrl + '', '_blank');
      if (win) {
        win.focus();
      } else {
        alert('Please allow popups for this website');
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
}, 400)
```

Note that I need to insert the element that I want to render into the `document.body`, and after the rendering is done just immediately remove it from the body, this is flickering and distracts users. Also I needed to add a timeout otherwise sometimes the images in the element to render did not show correctly.

The question I ask is how to make it more nice so that main web page does not display the form for half a second? Also how to avoid using timeout and use some sort of completenes event instead?

The library I use is: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

Comment: Can you put a fixed-position `<div>` above the `node` you want to convert to an image? You could give that `<div>` a solid white background, so it covers the node's contents while you perform the rendering, and then you could remove it when it's finished.

Comment: what do you mean "does not display the form" ? what form?

Comment: @vsync the "form" here refers to the document I want to render "The Investor Application Certification Form", the contents of which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure it that would work, but have you tried positioning your form out of visible part of your page? Can you create image of it if it has something like position: fixed, top: -1000px?